# hibernate hikaricp datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, hikaricp

I tried changing the connection pool of my webapp from c3p0 to hikaricp.

here is my configuration.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider">

    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="${hikari.dataSourceClassName}" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="${hikari.maximumPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="${hikari.maxLifetime}" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="${hikari.idleTimeout}" />

    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
            <prop key="user">${jdbc.username}</prop>
            <prop key="password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

i am getting an error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'dataSourceClassName' of bean class [org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider]: Bean property 'dataSourceClassName' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:231)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:280)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    ... 32 more
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider` is not a `javax.sql.DataSource`. It's an internal component of Hibernate.

Change your configuration to use `com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource` instead of `org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider`

Comment: Thank you so much. didn't see that.